# Adobe Air Activate/Deactivate events doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I can't get work Activate and Deactivate events for my Android Application. When I am running it on Windows it is working.

In constructor of the document class I tried this:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE , onActivate, false, 0, true);  
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE , onDeactivate, false, 0, true);
```

and

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE , onActivate, false, 0, true);
this.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE , onDeactivate, false, 0, true);
```

and

```
 this.stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE , onActivate, false, 0, true);
    this.stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE , onDeactivate, false, 0, true);
```

this are the functions:

```
private function onActivate(e:Event) : void {
    new BubbleSnd().play();
}

private function onDeactivate(e:Event) : void {
    new AlertSnd().play();
}
```

Why I can't hear the sounds on my phone? 
When I press on home button, I deactivate focus so I should hear the sound...but nothing happends.
I have used those Events few months ago on another Android App and then they works fine.
Thank you!

Comment: Here's activate code that should work:
private var application: NativeApplication;
application = NativeApplication.nativeApplication;
application.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, activate);

private function activate(e: Event): void {
  //do whatever
}

Comment: this is working. Thank you. Put yout question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's standard activate code that should work:

```
private var application: NativeApplication; 
application = NativeApplication.nativeApplication; 
application.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, activate); 
private function activate(e: Event): void { 
  //do whatever 
}
```